# Why does this command fail ? Cisco Nexus5548

Tags: cisco, cisco-nexus

I'm wondering why the following command is invalid ? I don't have access to the switch, only to a read-only web-interface. It's a Nexus5548, and it does have an interface named "port-channel1". The output is from an automation-framework. Is it possible port-channel is a reserved keyword ?

```
[redacted]# show interface port-channel1 status
                                                        ^
% Invalid command at '^' marker.
[redacted]#
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you first created the the Po1 interface? The command will fail if the interface does not exist.

Comment: Does this 'read-only webinterface' modify or filter commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is

> show interface port-channel *interface-number* [options]

So in your case

> show interface port-channel 1 status

Note the space between the port-channel and the 1.

Cfr. https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/sw/5_x/nx-os/interfaces/command/reference/if_commands.html